# C++ ifstream error using string as opening file path

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I get this error when I try running the program.What might be the problem as the code is correct as far as I can see.

Here is the error

std::basic_fstream::basic_fstream(std::string&, const openmode&)'

**Here is the code**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string fileName;
int frequencyArray[26];
char character;

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    frequencyArray[i] = 0;

cout << "Please enter the name of file: ";
getline(cin, fileName);

fstream inFile(fileName, fstream::in);  // to read the file

if (inFile.is_open())
{
    while (inFile >> noskipws >> character)
    {
        // if alphabet
        if (isalpha(character))
        {
            frequencyArray[(int)toupper(character) - 65]++;
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    cout << "Letter frequencies are as: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        cout << (char)(i + 65) << " = " << frequencyArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid File. Exiting...";
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although C++11 defines a `std::fstream` constructor that accepts a `std::string` as input, Microsoft's implementation of `std::fstream` apparently does not:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a33ahe62.aspx#basic_fstream__basic_fstream

You will have to use the `std::string::c_str()` method to pass the filename:

```
fstream inFile(fileName.c_str(), fstream::in);
```

That being said, consider using `std::ifstream` instead:

```
ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change

```
fstream inFile(fileName, fstream::in);
```

to

```
fstream inFile(fileName.c_str(), fstream::in);
```